# How to use .htaccess to redirect all files under a web sub directory to another server?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm migrating a portion of our web server to a new one. I'd like to write a .htaccess to redirect all files under a web sub directory to another server. All the examples I've looked at are redirecting domain or specific files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this in `/subdir/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ http://new.server.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```